# i am not able to upload the envato template as i tried the possible solution like changing PHP version

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

i am not able to upload the envato template as i tried the possible solution like changing PHP version and i dont know what is getting wrong so somone will help me fix the issue.

[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psMOV.png)
[PHP Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrs3l.png)
as i tried all the visible version.
[Zip folder is also enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3GXh.png)

i tried changing PHP Versions checking Elementor  setting for ZIP upload